# Flutter: Future.doWhile end timeout exception

Tags: flutter

I have problem with dosen't stop iteration in Future.doWhile after catch timeout error.

Below is code my example function:

```dart
 Future<void> testFunction() async {
    print(">>> start test");

    int sec = 0;
    await Future.doWhile(() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
      sec += 5;
      if (sec >= 60) {
        print("> end doWhile after 60 seconds");
        return false;
      }
      print("> elapsed $sec seconds");
      return true;
    }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 20)).then(print).catchError(print);

    print(">>> end test");
  }
```

and result:

```
I/flutter ( 6081): >>> start test
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 5 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 10 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 15 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): TimeoutException after 0:00:20.000000: Future not completed
I/flutter ( 6081): >>> end test
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 20 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 25 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 30 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 35 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 40 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 45 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 50 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > elapsed 55 seconds
I/flutter ( 6081): > end doWhile after 60 seconds
```

Why doWhile's iteration works after catch timeout error?

Comment: check similar: `void main() {
  print('start');
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 6), () {
    print('delayed');
    return 'delayed ret val';
  })
  .timeout(Duration(seconds: 3), onTimeout: () {
    print('tout');
    return 'tout ret val';
  }).then(print);
}`

Answer (score 3):

The timeout method

```
Future<T> timeout (

    Duration timeLimit,
    {FutureOr<T> onTimeout(
    )}

)
```

isn't meant to stop the execution of the Future it's called on. You can think of it equivalent to simply a delayed method which waits for *timeLimit* duration for the Future to return a value. If Future doesn't complete in *timeLimit* you get a chance to do some work with *onTimeout* so code doesn't break.

If you really want to stop execution of doWhile method in your case, you could implement it like this:

```
Future<void> testFunction() async {
  print(">>> start test");
  var toContinue = true;

  int sec = 0;
  await Future.doWhile(() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    sec += 1;
    if (sec >= 5) {
      print("> end doWhile after 5 seconds");
      return false;
    }
    print("> elapsed $sec seconds");
    return toContinue;
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 3), onTimeout: () {
    toContinue = false;
    print('> Timed Out');
  });
  print(">>> end test");
}
```

Output:

```
>>> start test
> elapsed 1 seconds
> elapsed 2 seconds
> Timed Out
>>> end test
> elapsed 3 seconds
```

Even [this author](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-guide-to-using-futures-in-flutter-for-beginners-ebeddfbfb967#9bc2) is wrong about timeout method

> If you run the code about. You’ll see 0 timed out and you'll never see Delay complete for Future 0.

For further reading:
[Future.timeout documention is misleading](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42318)
[Add possibility to truly cancel/dispose Fututre](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42855)